# Creating a simple text editor in C++

Tags: c++

I'm in my CS162 class and my assignment for this week is to create a very, very simple text editor which prompts the user to input a paragraph, type # when finished, and then the program will make simple edits such as capitalizing any beginning-of-the-sentence words and changing common errors such as "teh" to "the."  Now, I always have trouble getting started with these things; I know exactly how I'm going to correct the errors (have the program search for misspellings and replace those words with the correct spelling/using .upper to change to upper case), but I can't get started on simply having the user input a paragraph and end it with #.  Would I use a loop that allows the user to continue typing until they type #? what would that look like?  Sorry if this seems excessively basic; I just always have trouble getting started with programs, since I am a very early beginner.  Thank You.

Comment: Why can't you let them type until the hit Return?

Comment: I don't know... that would be a lot easier, wouldn't it? No, we have to do the # thing... it's a requirement, and I don't know why.

Comment: Just to be clear, they end the paragraph with `#` and then press return, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CONIO.H

You can use functions like:

getch() - reads a character from the console without buffer or echo

kbhit() which determines if a keyboard key was pressed.

to get what you're looking for.

Edit:
This is from user Falcom Momot, for Linux systems:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <termios.h>
char getch() {
    char buf = 0;
    struct termios old = {0};
    if (tcgetattr(0, &old) < 0)
            perror("tcsetattr()");
    old.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;
    old.c_lflag &= ~ECHO;
    old.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;
    old.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
    if (tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &old) < 0)
            perror("tcsetattr ICANON");
    if (read(0, &buf, 1) < 0)
            perror ("read()");
    old.c_lflag |= ICANON;
    old.c_lflag |= ECHO;
    if (tcsetattr(0, TCSADRAIN, &old) < 0)
            perror ("tcsetattr ~ICANON");
    return (buf);
```

}

Comment: What if OP isn't on a windows machine?

Comment: Ah right... so on a linux machine this can be done using termios.h  I'll edit in some code I have bookmarked somewhere...

Comment: Honestly my guess is that OP's user is allowed to hit return.  The # bit is just to distinguish a newline in the stream from what is consider a newline ending a paragraph.  IOW he can type 5 sentences and hit enter 5 times but it isn't a paragraph until it ends in a #.  This actually makes it easier to avoid dealing with individual key strokes.

Comment: That is true, and it would be a much easier way of doing what he wants.

Comment: ahhhh, wait, this must be what my professor meant. Wow, I feel pretty stupid now.  Thanks so much, guys.

Comment: Haha at least you figured it out!